# How to handle case-insensitive SPARQL data in MarkLogic

Tags: rdf, sparql, marklogic

I'm trying to understand how best to handle literals in Marklogic SPARQL data which may be in any case.  I'd like to be able to do a case insensitive search but I believe that isn't possible with semantic queries. For a simplistic example I want:

```
SELECT *
WHERE { ?s ?p "Red"}
```

and

```
SELECT *
WHERE { ?s ?p "red"}
```

to return all values whether the object is "Red", "RED", "red" or "rED".

My data is from another source which has variable capitalisation rules. At the moment the only thing I can think of is to add an extra triple which always contains the text in lower case so I can always search on that value.  Alternatively, would it make sense to create some new range query in MarkLogic with a case insensitive collation (if that's possible on triple data)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write SPARQL query that efficiently matches string literals while ignoring case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660030/how-to-write-sparql-query-that-efficiently-matches-string-literals-while-ignorin)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a filter that ignores case.

```
select * where {
  ?s ?p ?o
  FILTER (lcase(str(?o)) = "red")
}
```

[Based on the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660030/how-to-write-sparql-query-that-efficiently-matches-string-literals-while-ignorin).

Edit: I asked Steve Buxton, MarkLogic's PM for semantics features, and he suggested this:

```
let $store := sem:store( (), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("sem:object"), "red", "case-insensitive") )
return
  sem:sparql('
    SELECT ?o
    WHERE {
      ?s ?p ?o
      FILTER (lcase(str(?o)) = "red")
    }', (), (), $store
 )
```

sem:store is a MarkLogic 8 (now available through [Early Access](http://www.marklogic.com/what-is-marklogic/marklogic/)) function that selects a group of triples. The SPARQL query then runs on the reduced set, limiting the number of triples that need to be filtered.

Comment: You can also use [cts:contains](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:contains). A string query (2nd-argument) is coerced to a [cts:word-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:word-query), which is case-insensitive for lower-case strings.

Comment: @joemfb good suggestion, though it should be pointed out that those are product-specific extensions that are not part of the SPARQL standard, and so queries using them will not be portable to other SPARQL stores.

Comment: Plus one as this is a good solution. Minus one because if it's based on another answer, there's a good chance that you should just flag the question as a duplicate.  There's nothing the matter with a duplicate question, and it's better to have a canonical answer rather than lots of very similar questions floating around.

Comment: It's the same question asked about different platforms, which allows for potentially different answers.