# Is it possible to perform diacritic, case sensitive/insensitive and wildcarded search on triples in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

How can I perform
`diacritic-sensitive` `diacritic-insensitive` `case-insensitive` `case-sensitive` `wildcarded` search on triples stored in MarkLogic DB with good performance (by making use of triples index)

Would be great if explained with examples.

Please provide any tutorial on the same if available.

Comment: When you ask to do a diacritic-sensitive and a diacritic-insensitive search do you mean you want to do two different searches, because those two options can't be used together.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255449/how-to-handle-case-insensitive-sparql-data-in-marklogic?